# Copy text from asp:textbox to clipboard

Tags: javascript, textbox

i have got a textbox with id txt1 which gets text from code behind and a button next it. i want to copy that text to clipboard so i can paste it on other places. i found few on net but could not get them work. please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you will need the help of SWF object to copy to the clipBoard like [this](http://davidwalsh.name/clipboard)